# How to use a JFrame button to launch a second JFrame without launching more JFrames in Java?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, actionlistener

My program is supposed to launch a second JFrame and print a statement when the button is clicked, but it always launches three JFrames and prints three statements. I need it to only print out one statement and launch one Jframe. Here is the code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.text.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Test extends JPanel implements ActionListener {
    JButton button = new JButton();
    String buttonString = "Buttontext";

    public Test() {
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        button.setText("Buttontext");
        button.setCursor(Cursor.getDefaultCursor());
        button.setMargin(new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0));
        button.setBounds(700, 400, 100, 20);
        button.setActionCommand(buttonString);
        button.addActionListener(this);
        this.add(button);
    }

    public static void createandshowGUI() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Frame");
        frame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.white);
        Dimension dim = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        frame.setSize(dim.width, dim.height);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(new Test());
        frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createandshowGUI();
            }
        });
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (buttonString.equals(e.getActionCommand())) {
            System.out.println("creating a new frame");
            newframe();
        }
    }

    public void newframe() {
        JFrame frame2 = new JFrame();
        Dimension dim = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        frame2.setSize(dim.width / 2, dim.height / 2);
        frame2.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame2.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        frame2.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You keep adding an `ActionListener` to your `button` in your `paintComponent(Graphics)` method. That means each time this method is invoked, you add another `ActionListener` to your button. Therefore, each time the button is pressed, it will do the same thing however many times that method is invoked before you press the button.

Answer (score 2):

First see [**The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9554657/2587435) - The popular answer here is BAD.

A much cleaner approach would be to use `CardLayout` to switch between different `JPanel`s. The below runnable example can be see [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21422694/2587435). Also see [**How to Use CardLayout**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html)

[image]

---

Another approach is to use a *modal* `JDialog`. The below runnable example can be seen [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20286447/2587435). Also see [**How to Use Make Dialogs**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

`paintComponent()` is called every time the panel is asked to paint itself. That request happens for a lot of reasons - including repainting the panel if another window has moved on top of it, or if the panel is resized. Any code in `paintComponent()` should *only* be used for painting the component.

So, this is not the right place for `button.addActionListener()`. In fact, all of your  `button` code, including `this.add(button)`, should happen somewhere else, probably in `createandshowGUI`.

Your program does not need to override `paintComponent()`. You can rely on a JPanel to paint all of the components that have been added to it (in fact, `super.paintComponent()` does exactly that). You only need to override `paintComponent()` if you're doing something unique in drawing the panel (for example, putting a background image in the panel). In your case, you just have to add the button to the panel and you're done.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create multiple windows, use a `JDesktopPane`. Add `JInternalFrame`s to them as needed. That way you will have a single, top-level window with child windows inside.