# displaying class to another class

Tags: java, swing, jframe

Hi im doing my main page for my program and i want to happen is when i click the maze button, the Maze class would appear and same with the hexagonal button.

Can you tell me what is wrong with my program?everytime i run and click a button nothing happens.thanks for the huge help.

```
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.lang.*;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Center extends JFrame {

Maze x = new Maze();
HEX h = new HEX();


JPanel jp = new JPanel();
JButton jb = new JButton("Maze");
JButton jb1 = new JButton("Hex");

JFrame frame = new JFrame();


public Center()
{
    frame.setTitle("Prims Maze Generation");
    //setVisible(true);
    //setSize(400,200);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setSize(400, 200);
    jp.add(jb);
    jp.add(jb1);
    frame.add(jp);

    jb.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {

            x.setVisible(true);
            frame.pack();
        }
    });
    jb.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e)
        {
            h.setVisible(true);

        }
    });

}

public static void main(String args[])
{
    Center p = new Center();
}

 }
```

Comment: what is Maze n Hex extending from?

Answer (score 1):

Before anything, your class is already a `JFrame`, either use the class `JFrame` or use the instance `JFrame` (and remove the JFrame extension - just do this), **don't do *both***!

Your problem and **simple fix** (but may not yield your expected results).

- `JFrame` has a default `BorderLayout`, which when you add components, will be automatically placed at the `BorderLayout.CENTER` position. Each position may only have *one* component. You are trying to add *three* components to the `CENTER` without even knowing it. The fix if to specify a different position for each component, i.e. `BorderLayout.NORTH`, `BorderLayout.SOUTH`

Here is the **much cleaner fix**

- Use a `CardLayout`. Assuming `Maze` and `Hex` are already `JPanels` (if they aren't then make then so. Do something like this

  ```
  CardLayout card = new CardLayout();
  JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel(card);
  JPanel firstVisiblePanel = new JPanel();
  Hex hex = new Hex();
  Maze maze = new Maze();

  public Center() {
      mainPanel.add(firstVisiblePanel, "initialPanel");
      mainPanel.add(hex, "hex");
      mainPanel.add(maze, "maze");

      final JButton jbtHex = new JButton("Hex");
      jbtHex.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
          public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
              card.show(mainPanel, "hex");
          }
      });
      // do the same as above for the other panels.
      ....
      frame.add(mainPanel); <------- This is the ONLY panel you add to the frame.
      frame.setVisible(true); <----- Should be the LAST thing you do.
  }
  ```

---

See more at [**How to Use CardLayout**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) and a running [**SO Example**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21422694/2587435)

Answer (score 0):

I had something like this happen to me once. Try resizing the frame AFTER using the setVisible() method. Try this:

```
public Center()
{
frame.setTitle("Prims Maze Generation");
//setVisible(true);
//setSize(400,200);
setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame.setVisible(true);
frame.setSize(400, 200);
jp.add(jb);
jp.add(jb1);
frame.add(jp);

jb.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {

        x.setVisible(true);
        frame.setSize(400, 200);
        frame.pack();
    }
});
jb.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e)
    {
        h.setVisible(true);
        frame.setSize(400, 200);

    }
});
}
```

Comment: i already tried it but still, it doesn't work. nothing happens if you clicked the button.

Comment: Can you upload the Eclipse project (If you're using Eclipse)?

Comment: where can i upload?sorry new to this thing. :)